# Is it possible to map multiple components as composite ids?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Is it possible to use multiple components as the composite-id in a Hibernate HBM mapping file? In the snippet below, TradeServiceId and ChargeId are actual classes.

I want those two fields to be the composite primary keys of this table

```
    <component name="tradeServiceId" class="com.ucpb.tfs.domain.service.TradeServiceId" insert="false" update="false">
        <property name="tradeServiceId" column="serviceInstructionId" type="string" />
    </component>

    <component name="chargeId" class="com.ucpb.tfs.domain.reference.ChargeId" insert="false" update="false">
        <property name="chargeId" column="chargeId" type="string" />
    </component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO it's not possible since compositeId only supports KeyProperty and Keyreferences. However it is possible to use IUserType and maybe ICompositeUserType which means you can implement the conversion yourself.